# How to center a custom content thumbnail (Bootstrap 3.3.6)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started using Bootstrap and it's awesome so far. However I have one question, I created a content container and put a picture in it and I'm only going to have one in the row and I want it to go in the center of the page. I have tried a lot of things but to no avail, they don't work. Any help is appreciated! I'm also using Bootstrap version 3.3.6

This is my code for the container

```
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="random.jpg" alt="...">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3><center>I want the whole container in the center of the page.</center></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap has built in classes for you to use instead of the default  tag. Try this for your image:

```
<img class="center-block" src="yourimage.png" />
```

Comment: I'm sure I tried that before
Aaaand nope, didn't work :(

Comment: Your div is also set up to only cover half the page. Change your col-sm-6 col-md-6 to col-xs-12. Center-block should work so I'm not sure what the problem is there.

Comment: If I do that, it get's centered. However, the outer bracket/line/container thing extends from the end to end of the page and doesn't just cover the picture as it should.

Comment: Your col-xs-12 div will make a container for the width of the full page. Your thumbnail div should be the one making the border for just the picture/ caption. Check your thumnail css or post it here so I can help you through it.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the CDN so I'm using the default css. https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css is the link im sure

Comment: Where does your thumbnail class come from? How are you drawing the border?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what that exactly means haha, I'm just tryna learn as I go. I simply used the preset style from Bootstrap and just copied and pasted the code above from their site under the "Components" tab that has all the features. I also have it wrapped in a header tag if that makes a difference.

Comment: No worries. If you're a beginner try to take the time to understand each line of your code, when something goes wrong it will make it much easier to figure out the problem. I would say lose the thumbnail div. If you just want the border around the image you can make the class for that center-block-thumbnail. The more specific you are the easier it will be for me to help.

Comment: Hey, thanks for all ur help! I just searched around and found out about this offset function and I wrote this

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3">

And it properly set it to the middle!